# Embedded SATA on my PE R440

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I purchased a PowerEdge R440 with embedded SATA and am wondering is it possible to set up a different RAID with the drives in them? i.e. RAID 1 for the 480GB drives and RAID 6 for the 12TB drives or do I need to have the hardware (H730P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the RAID controller if you want to do hardware RAID.

If you want to do software RAID, ZFS, etc., then the onboard SATA ports and/or a non-RAID HBA will do fine.